# Pusher doubles logs in console and app dashboard

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, pusher

I'm faced with a weird situation, where using Pusher with Laravel 5.6 (it's important to point out that everything is working just fine), **I am receiving doubled notifications** (both on console @ the developer's console in the browser and the Debug Console in Pusher's app).

I can not find any doubled code of pusher in my app, so it annoys me a little.

Here is the screenshot of the code from developer's console:
[Developer's console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAsJC.png).

And here from Debug Console:[Debug Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfbxA.png).

Also, I attach the most important part's of the code:

**//view.blade.php**

```
<script type="application/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    Pusher.logToConsole = true;
    var pusher = new Pusher('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', {
        cluster: 'eu',
        encrypted: true
    });

    var channel = pusher.subscribe('update-date-channel');
    channel.bind('App\\Events\\Event', function(data) {
        $(".list-group").find("#" + data.updatedItemId).html(data.updatedDate);
    });

})
```

**// Controller (By which I am sending updated values)**

```
public function addbid(Request $request)
{
    /*
    ...
    */
    event(new Event($updatedDate = $newDate->toArray("date")["formatted"], $request -> id));
    Session::flash('message', "Bid added succesfully!");
    return Redirect::back();
}
```

**// And here comes the whole Event file from App\Events\Event**

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class Event implements ShouldBroadcast
{
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

public $updatedDate;
public $updatedItemId;

/**
 * Create a new event instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($updatedDate, $updatedItemId)
{
    $this->updatedDate = $updatedDate;
    $this->updatedItemId = $updatedItemId;
}

/**
 * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
 */
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return ['update-date-channel'];
}
}
```

**In resources/assets/js** I did not change anything in app.js, in bootstrap.js I just uncommented the last part (the one which starts: "import Echo from 'laravel-echo'...").

Comment: It's because you are subscribing to the same channel twice (you can see this in the browser logs). You could try putting a log line before `var channel = pusher.subscribe('update-date-channel');` to check it's not being called twice. It would also be worth searching for other occurrences of calls to `subscribe()`.

Comment: @WillSewell alright, but Im looking at all of the edited files, and I can not see double subscription anywhere... Only in view.blade.php provided in the first post, any ideas? Thanks for Your interesting in this topic by the way :)

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed one thing:

When changed jQuery version from 3.3.1 to for example 1.12.4, then I recieved some error from the script, which is above pusher (it's just about the other script), so then the logs showed only once...